# Correct handler in AppleScript to respond to the "open" Unix command for a custom URL handling applet

Tags: macos, url, applescript, appleevents

I'm trying to write a simple AppleScript application that handles sftp:// and sshfs:// URLs on my Mac.  Based on a good [guide on how to create a custom URL handler app in AppleScript](http://www.macosautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/index.html), I wrote [a small app](https://github.com/netj/MacSSHFSURLHandler) as follows and it works well when I click on a URL with the corresponding schemes.  Actual work is done in a separate shell script that calls sshfs(FUSE), and I'm using AppleScript just to interface it with the OS.

```
on open location theURL
    set cmd to (quoted form of (get POSIX path of (path to resource "sshfs.sh" in directory "Scripts"))) & " " & theUrl
    do shell script cmd
end open location
```

However, **this custom URL handler AppleScript app doesn't work if I use the `open` command from Terminal**, e.g.,

```
open sftp://host/path
```

I tried adding other handlers and found the command-line way invokes `on run argv` handler instead of the one I've written, but can't figure out how to access the passed URL argument.  I can access the URL correctly when the script is invoked directly, e.g., `osascript my.applescript sftp://host/path`.  Tried ASObjC Runner, but did not help.

**Is there a standard handler or a method in an AppleScript application for receiving the arguments passed over the `open` Unix command?**  It seems it relies on AppleEvents, but I can't find a good reference describing how to play the same magic between the command and native apps using AppleScript.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just handle it in your "on run handler"? Something like this...

```
on run argv
    set theArg to item 1 of argv
    if theArg starts with "sftp://" then
        open location theArg
    else
        -- do the normal applescript code
    end if
end run
```

Or are you saying the "open" unix command doesn't pass the argument?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this was exactly what I tried.  The `argv` for the run handler is set to `current application` somehow when I use the "open" unix command, so the `item 1 of argv` gives an error.  It is a list of strings though, when I invoke directly with osascript.  Weird, isn't it?